# Representing Id's based on a prefix Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have a database with a table with companies ID's and prefixes. Currently when I query the DB for information I organize it by the company ID's, I want to also display the prefixes associated with the id's in the query

```
Id    CoId  PartnerCoId
3221    1   3   
3220    1   4
```

here I would like to have the company prefixes shown next to the ID's lets say 1 = DBZ, 3 = TRE, and 4 = TYU

```
Id   CoId  PartnerCoId  coPrefix  partnerPrefix
3221    1   3            dbz         tre
3220    1   4            dbz         tyu
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: What is a prefix? Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: The prefixes for companies are in a table called Companies, which contains the CoId field as well as the Prefix field.  I know I can join the tables together but the only columns I want from the Companies table is Prefix but I want it twice, once for CoID and again for PartnerCoID. coPrefix and partnerPrefix do not exist in either table, I want to generate them based on the other columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join to the prefix table twice, once for the CoId and once for the PartnerId

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  CoId,
  PartnerCoId,
  mc.Prefix as coPrefix,
  pc.Prifix as partnerPrefix
FROM Table t
JOIN PrefixTable mc
  ON t.CoId = mc.CoId
JOIN PrefixTable pc
  ON t.PartnerCoId = pc.CoId
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I had no idea you could join twice on the same table.